# Files.write ends up with an empty file when JVM exits

Tags: java, concurrency, nio

Gone a looong road to isolate my issue, and managed to pinpoint it to the following tests. Everything works fine when the threads have enough time to finish, but with below setup I end up occasionally with empty files. This happens about 1/15 of the times I run the test. The issue seems to be on write, i.e. the file seems to be actually empty.

```
import lombok.Synchronized;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class Test{

    File dummyFile=new File("/tmp/foo.txt"); //initially "foo"
    String dummyText="foo";
    @Test
    void test() throws Exception{
        assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));
        spamAndTest();

        for(int i = 0; i< 100 ; i++){
            spamAndTestInThread(i);
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
        assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));
    }

    @Synchronized
    public static String read(File f){


        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
        Path p = f.toPath();

        String ret=null;
        try {
            ret = new String(Files.readAllBytes(p),charset);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ExUtils.handle(ex);
            return null;
        }




        if(ret.trim().length()==0){

            throw new RuntimeException("WTF, empty file:" +p);

        }
        return ret;


    }

    private void spamAndTestInThread(int i) {
        Thread tt= new Thread("spam"){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 0; i< 1000 ; i++){
                    save(dummyFile,dummyText);

                }
            }
        };
        tt.start();
    }


    @Synchronized
    private void save(File file, String data) {

        Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

        try {
            Files.write(file.toPath(),data.getBytes(charset));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

}
```

So, all signs point to this being caused by save failing when JVM is terminating. I'm running this on IntelliJ test runner but don't think this is the case as the original issue also happens in production when the JVM is terminated on an unfortunate moment. Also, I don't seem to be able to reproduce this when there's only 1 thread running.

Shouldn't the Files.write be able to handle JVM terminations out of the box? If not, how to handle it?

Using Oracle JDK 8 both locally and in prod.

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm not talking about power outages/JVM crashes but cases where shutdownhooks are run normally. Also good to note that the file is always fully empty, i.e. it does not die in the middle of a write.

EDIT2:

I tried this out with a far longer string and this time got it to cut in the middle & reproduced this with just 2 extra threads.

EDIT3:

Tried adding shutdown hooks and yes they're being run after the test. So, would expect those writes to be able to finish but apparently no.

Comment: How can java code handle abrupt termination of JVM for example when power is down?

Comment: I mean cases where shutdownhooks get run normally etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a JVM-terminates-too-soon issue. Your tests are spawning new, _non-daemon_ threads which means the JVM _can't_ terminate until those threads die.

Comment: There is no synchronization between your `read()` and `write()` methods. It can therefore easily happen that you try to read the file just at the moment when `Files.write` truncated it and before it started to write the bytes.

Comment: @ThomasKläger  lombok's @ Synchronized  handles it

Comment: lombok's @Synchronized does however **not** synchronize between static methods and instance methods. Static methods synchronize on a static field `$LOCK`, whereas instance methods synchronize on an instance field `$lock` -  see the description at https://projectlombok.org/features/Synchronized

Comment: @ThomasKläger ah, that was actually some mistake when editing & copypasting the code to here. Issue is fixed now, wasn't that but ty anyways

Comment: If adding sleep calls makes your code work then you likely have race conditions. I created my own tests to try and replicate the behavior you're seeing. It's only when I comment out the appropriate `synchronized` blocks that I see any failures.

Answer (score 0):

In your test method you are reading the file before writing in it. How you are ensuring that the dummy file will always contain text "foo".

```
assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));
spamAndTest();
```

You should write the text in file first and then read if. Check if changing this order could solve your problem.

```
spamAndTest();
assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));
```

Are you sure that all thread executed successfully in between 100ms?

```
Thread.sleep(100);
assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));
```

There could be a possibility a thread just truncate a file and 
 at that time `assertEquals(dummyText,read(dummyFile));` executed.

Comment: I dont want to append tho, I want to replace the file

Comment: The file will have "foo" there as it's written there previous tests unless they screw it up.  I am sure that the threads are *not* executed in that time.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to finally solve the issue by adding the following shutdown hook

```
Thread tt= new Thread(""){
            public void run(){
                //System.out.println("los shutdown hook (fileutils)");
                Sleep.millis(100); //to give other hooks time to start saving
                shutdown=true;
                while(writing)
                    System.err.println("halting shutdown while write in progress");
            }
        };
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(tt);
```

and then setting writing=true on start of save method + write=false on end of it + if(shutdown)return;